# is there a home phonecall monitor using server with regular modem?

Tags: untagged

Is there a way to monitor calls, call duration, and record calls using a fedora server with a regular 58k modem?

other things like voicemail, call block, etc would be great

Thanks

UPDATE: I also looked at asterisk.org which is awesome, but they need a very expensive special modem, and I would like to spend less than $50 USD.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, it depends. The modem you are wanting to use needs to be a [VoiceModem](http://www.modemsite.com/56k/voice.asp) to record the calls. If you are not recording and just detecting off hook duration any modem could work. If you want to do recording and playing sounds back to the caller you will need a modem that supports full duplex voice audio.

Comment: great thx, any software that goes with that?